# Angular - show post request income buffer before request finished

Tags: angularjs

I have an http post request to my server:

```
    $http.post(url, parameters, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
                log.innerHTML += $scope.PostDataResponse;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                        "<hr />status: " + status +
                        "<hr />headers: " + header +
                        "<hr />config: " + config;
                log.innerHTML += $scope.PostDataResponse;
            });
```

The thing is that my server is flushing content before the request has ended and I want the Angular request to react to every flush.

Example - the server is running a background process which updates whenever it finished a step in order to have the listener present a progress bar.

What is the right way of getting these updates with angular and HTTP post requests ?

Comment: `.success` & `.error` are already deprecated since angular `1.5`

Comment: use $http.get().then() `$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
 ...  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    ...
  });`

Comment: @AlainIb i've done that with a post request, but the success callback return the whole response, while the server flush the response with parts... i want to run a code whenever a new part is being flushed

Comment: sorry i don't get what you say. can you explain more please

Comment: My server has a long backend process.
During this process he keeps flushing text to the response.
I want to response in my code to the this text, even when the request is not done yet.
for example: he will send me an update about were we are in the process, i want to be able to catch that and use that.
currently i receive a blank response which will be updated with the full response only once the request was ended